# Ruby regex insert new lines between adjacent methods

Tags: ruby, regex, sed

I am trying to add new lines at appropriate places in my ruby files.
Some of the files have code like below:

```
def abc
  ...
end
def pqr
  ...
end
```

I want to add new lines at appropriate places like below:

```
def abc
  ...
end  

def pqr
  ...
end
```

So that the code is more readable. The initial regex that i have come up with is `def.*?def` with the `m` switch which matches based on the `def` keyword. But that regex also matches def keywords which already are separated by a blank new line. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

You could do something like `/end\ndef/` (you might need to use \r\n, depending on the line ending mode you are using in your editor).

This will match a literal `end` followed by a line return and immediately afterwards, a literal `def`.

Simply substitute in an extra line break, and it should work fine!

Comment: +1 Thanks! Really simple solution. It works on rubular.com but does not seem to be working in vim/sed. Any clues?

Comment: This seems to work nicely for me, in vim: `:%s/end\ndef/def\r\rend/g`

Comment: MacVim is saying `Pattern not found: end\ndef`

Comment: Hm, you could try this `:%s/end\_.def/end\r\rdef/g`, `\_.` should match any newline characters.

Comment: Same thing :( `Pattern not found end\_.def`. sed is also not matching anything.

Answer (score 1):

Try [`Enumerable#slice_before`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-slice_before) on your lines:

```
File.readlines('foo.rb').slice_before(/^\s*def\b/).flat_map do |group|
  group << "\n" if group.last =~ /^\s*end\b/
  group
end.join
```